# More instructions in lambda function body

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

As I know, I am able to define lambda functions in F# like that

```
(fun arg -> arg * arg)
```

But how can I extend the body of that definition to more than one expression? In some pseudo-code, it could look like that:

```
(fun arg -> {
    log "abcd"
    arg * arg
})
```

I need it to do some side effects.

Comment: That's basically it, just remove the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

F# is whitespace- and indentation-sensitive. Nesting of blocks of code is determined by how they are indented to the right.

For your specific example, in order to nest multiple expressions in a function body, simply indent them to the right at least one space:

```
let f1 = fun arg -> arg * arg

let f2 = fun arg ->
    log "abcd"
    arg * arg
```

An alternative way of including several expressions is separating them with a semicolon:

```
let f3 = fun arg -> log "abcd"; arg * arg
```

In general, semicolon may be used in F# instead of a line break in most circumstances.

If you need to use such multiline lambda expression as an argument for another function (e.g. `List.map`), you may need to enclose the whole body in parentheses:

```
[1;2;3]
|> List.map ( fun x -> 
      log "abcd"
      x*x )
```

This is required not because of the indentation, but merely because without parentheses this would be a syntactically incorrect program: the keyword `fun` would appear to be an argument passed to `List.map`, which can't happen, because `fun` is a keyword. This rule applies to one-line lambda expressions just as well:

```
[1;2;3]
|> List.map ( fun x -> x*x )
```

You can avoid the parentheses with a "pipe left" operator:

```
let squareAll = 
    List.map <| fun x -> 
        log "abcd"
        x*x

let squares = squareAll [1;2;3]
```

In this case, parentheses are not needed, because even without them the keyword `fun` does not appear, from the syntax point of view, to be an argument to `List.map`.

Keep in mind, however, that the use of "pipe left" may not always be convenient, since it conflicts with a much more common "pipe right" operator, for example:

```
[1;2;3] 
|> List.map <| fun x -> x*x
```

The above code would not compile, because it would be understood by the compiler as:

```
([1;2;3] |> List.map) 
<| fun x -> x*x
```

which is not correct, because `[1;2;3] |> List.map` is not a function.

In practice, it is most common to use parentheses.

Comment: Please do not tell beginners about the `<|` operator. This request comes from Don Syme himself. ;-)

Comment: Extremely curious. In Haskel, the equivalent `$` operator is quite ubiquitous.

Comment: Yes, but that is right associative; `<|` isn't, which makes its effect a little surprising at times. Don essentially said a) never use/show it in beginner code, b) try to avoid it, especially if you just want to avoid parentheses (which I mostly use it for) and c) never use it on the same line as `|>`. (From his keynote at the F# Exchange last week: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/11439-keynote-f-sharp-code-i-love)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thank You very much for that expert level explanation. It is also big shame for me to not remember about indentation-sensitive in that language. It is first language with that feature which I am learning. :)